# AWS Amplify with Angular - Stop URL redirecting to index

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, routes, aws-amplify

I have an Angular app that I recently migrated to AWS Amplify.  I am having a problem, though, with creating links to particular pages (for example, sending a confirmation link in an email).  Links automatically redirect to the index page.  The same thing happens if I try to navigate to a page by entering its URL in the address bar, or if I simply reload the page.

I have an app-routing.module.ts file that used to work before moving to Amplify.  When run from localhost, the links still work fine.  How do I fix this?

App-routing.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './intro/intro.module#IntroModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgSelectComponent } from './ng-select/ng-select.component';
import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
import { AmplifyAngularModule, AmplifyService } from 'aws-amplify-angular';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NgSelectComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxChartsModule,
    AmplifyAngularModule
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  providers: [
    AmplifyService,
    { provide: 'APIRoot', useValue: 'https://app.rivver-platform.com/api/' },
    { provide: 'colors1', useValue: ['#3dcc85','#ffbe5c','#7b64e0','#ff8370'] },
    { provide: 'colors1', useValue: ['#3dcc85','#ffbe5c','#7b64e0','#ff8370'] },
    { provide: 'colors2', useValue: ['#51c8e0','#7b64e0','#3dcc85','#ffbe5c'] }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component

```
<main [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)">
<router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</main>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { slideInAnimation } from './animations';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {MatIconRegistry} from '@angular/material/icon';
import { LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    slideInAnimation
    // animation triggers go here
  ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private loaded = false;
  constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private locationStrategy: LocationStrategy, private router: Router) {

  ngOnInit() {
    let _this = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      _this.loaded = true;
    },1);
  }
  prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    if (!this.loaded){
      history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
    }
    return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'];
  }

}
```

EDIT: I tried removing prepareRoute, AmplifyAngularModule, and AmplifyService but the problem persists.

Comment: Please provide your code..

Comment: @Sela What code?  The entire app?

Comment: Your app routing modules, and other component or two would do

Comment: @Sela Ok, fine.

Comment: I have the similar issue. When I run my app on localhost - routing is fine. When I deploy it on amplify, routes are always resulting in error - This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security purposes, AWS Amplify blocks all links from external sources and redirects them to the index.  To edit these rules, go to Rewrites and Redirects. The following page explains how to use these rules.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa